# How to DISTINCT COUNT with multiple criteria in BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

this is the table i have

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 327452 | 0 |
| B | 327478 | 8 |
| A | 1507089 | 1 |
| A | 1507089 | 4 |
| C | 1625746 | 9 |
| C | 1529 | 2 |
| B | 1625759 | 7 |
| B | 1625760 | 5 |
| A | 20366530 | 3 |
| C | 1529 | 0 |

So in Col4 i want to get a count of unique value with multiple criteria, which ist suppose to give me something like this:

| ColA | ColB | ColC | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 327452 | 0 | 2 |
| B | 327478 | 8 | 3 |
| A | 1507089 | 1 | 2 |
| A | 1507089 | 4 | 2 |
| C | 1625746 | 9 | 2 |
| C | 1529 | 2 | 2 |
| B | 1625759 | 7 | 3 |
| B | 1625760 | 5 | 3 |
| A | 20366530 | 3 | 2 |
| C | 1529 | 0 | 2 |

in Spreadsheet i can just simply use a formula like this `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C,B:B=B2,D:D>0)))`

But now i try to learn BIGQUERY and try to write a code like this but it didn't work:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ColA
COUNT(DISTINCT ColB IF((ColA=[@[ColA]])*(ColC>0)))
FROM
  `mi-trial-365509.Trial.MI 17012022`
LIMIT
  1000
```

Can someone please help me here?, I'm really new in BIGQUERY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One canonical way to do this uses a join:

```sql
SELECT t1.ColA, t1.ColB, t1.ColC, COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0) AS Col4
FROM `mi-trial-365509.Trial.MI 17012022` t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ColA, COUNT(DISTINCT ColB) cnt
    FROM `mi-trial-365509.Trial.MI 17012022`
    WHERE ColC > 0
    GROUP BY ColA
) t2
    ON t2.ColA = t1.ColA;
```

Comment: It worked, but I'm so sorry seems like I've been confused about what I want to achieve before, please see my updated post, and I hope you're still willing to help me here sir!, thank you!

Comment: You have attempted to _totally_ rewrite your question which invalidates my answer.  _Don't do that_ ... ask a new question if you need help with something else.

Comment: ohh im so sorry, okay i will ask ne question then, thank you!

Comment: Would you help me with this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122592/how-to-pull-unique-value-and-add-distinct-count-multiple-criteria-in-bigquery) @tim-biegeleisen